# Analyse Javascript/Typescript project with SonarCloud and Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, sonarcloud

I have a project containing both Javascript and Typescript files. I'm using SonarCloud to analyse this project from an Azure DevOps pipeline.

I set the task *Prepare Analysis Configuration* in my build pipeline like this:

```
- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  inputs:
    SonarCloud: 'Sonarcloud'
    organization: 'MyOrg'
    scannerMode: 'CLI'
    configMode: 'manual'
    cliProjectKey: 'My key'
    cliProjectName: 'My name'
    cliSources: '.'
```

When running the pipeline, I have the following error in my pipeline on *Sonar Cloud Analyze* step

```
INFO: Found 1 tsconfig.json file(s): [/home/vsts/work/1/s/tsconfig.json]
##[error]ERROR: Cannot find module 'typescript'
##[error]ERROR: TypeScript dependency was not found and it is required for analysis.
ERROR: Install TypeScript in the project directory or use NODE_PATH env. variable to set TypeScript location, if it's located outside of project directory.

ERROR: TypeScript dependency was not found and it is required for analysis.
ERROR: Install TypeScript in the project directory or use NODE_PATH env. variable to set TypeScript location, if it's located outside of project directory.
##[error]ERROR: Missing TypeScript dependency
```

The analysis works well for javascript files but not for typescript files. I have the *typescript* package installed as dev dependency in my package.json but it seems it is ignored by SonarCloud.

The documentation and topics I found are related to SonarQube version but I can't figure out how to setup this with *SonarCloud*.

Comment: Have you tried adding a npm install task before these two tasks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `node_modules` folder in local project folder won't be added into source control if you're using Visual Studio.

And this error would occur since `Run Code Analysis` task can't find the dependency packages defined in your `package.json` file. My reproducible step:

[image]

Then I add one `npm install` task before `Prepare Analysis task` to install missing packages:

[image]

NodeJS is my project name. Also in Devops repos, this is the name of the folder where package.json exists.

Then this issue went away in my pipeline:

[image]

Hope it also helps for your issue :)

**In addition:** You can also choose to add local `node_modules` folder into source control if you want. But this is **not recommended** in Azure Devops Service.

Comment: Thank you! That works now. I had put the analysis step just before npm install.